# calling javascript/jquery function in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have aspx page in which i use updatepanel

some function i placed at the middle of page than on button client click i can't call them.

code like this does not work

**case 1:**

```
<%--some html--%>
<asp:Button ID="btnBotton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return callfunction();" Text="Submit"/>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <%--some content here--%>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <%--async trigger --%>
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callfunction() {//function placed at the middle of page
            alert('hello');
        }
    </script>
    <%--some html again--%>
</asp:Content>
```

and if i place my function at the end of page than i call function

**case 2:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <%--some html--%>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return callfunction();" Text="Submit"/>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <%--some content here--%>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <%--async trigger --%>
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <%--some html again--%>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callfunction() {//function placed at the middle of page
            alert('hello');
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

**so I want to know what is the issue with case 1? Why i am not able to call function**

Comment: i does not want to call function from code behind. It simple that on OnClientClick i want to call jquery function

Answer (score 0):

Updatepanel causes a full re-instantiation of the Page’s control tree and every single control runs through its life cycle events. JQuery and WebForms do not usually play nice. I believe you may be having some issues with nesting here, but its hard to tell without seeing the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

```
clientscript.registerstartupscript
```

it will help.

Comment: i does not want to call function from code behind. It simple that on OnClientClick i want to call jquery function